# ListView inside another ListView does not work

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, nested

I am stuck with a strange problem. I have a ListView inside another ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Graph}">    
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Node}">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LSC.Elements}">
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Entity}">
                    <TextBlock Text={Binding Name} />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView>
        <DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Edge}">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ListView>
```

All I get is the following exception:

```
Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception
```

Can you please explain to me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would check inner exception it would tell you that

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

You forgot about `ListView.ItemTemplate` or `ListView.Resources` (depending on how you want to do this) tag in the inner `ListView`. It should be:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LSC.Elements}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Entity}">
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Name} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

without that it assumes that your `DataTemplate` is an item and since you already specify `ItemSource` binding you get this error